# Find a value within a column, then change a value elsewhere on the same row

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I am working on a project with an Excel "database" to keep track of production of items. There have been cases of people scanning an item more than once, which causes problems when it's time to send to the client.

I have an alert popup, to prevent people from scanning an item more than once unless dealing with a rework. If the item is present in the "database", there is a MsgBox with vbYesNo buttons. If people click "Yes", it's a rework. If people click "No", it's an error and they exit the sub.

I need a way to handle the rework and have it change the values of the cells in the same row as the original item.

Here's the code I have so far.

```
Private Sub gbatchd_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer) 'Check DB for duplicate value

Set depo = dbgrids.Sheets("Deposition")
Set found = depo.Columns("A").Find(what:=valuetofind, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

valuetofind = gbatchd.Text
FR = depo.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If KeyCode = 13 Then
    For i = 1 To FR
        If gbatch.Cells(i, 1).Value = valuetofind Then
            MsgBox "This batch has already been deposited!" & vbCrLf & "Rework?", vbYesNo, "Rework?"
            If answer = vbNo Then
                Exit Sub
            Else
                depo.Cells(found.Row, 5).Value = "Rework"
            End If
        End If
    Next
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a specific question in there. What does "reworking" actually involve?

Comment: @SJR reworking involves rejecting some more items than initially, the item is being reworked because there was something wrong with it during screening. So everytime the item is reworked, the amount of a certain substance is lowered and all of that has to be traceable. I guess I could create a new row with that information and then merge it with the original row. But I think that will be a little more complicated.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use an *actual* database? Trying to enforce referential integrity is a little *more* than "complicated".

Comment: @Cominter I work for a company with very strict security policies. And since I'm fairly new in the company, they want me to work with what I have which is Excel.

Comment: The excel file is on the network for more users, or just on one computer for one user?

Comment: I would test for If answer = vbYes so you can avoid the exit sub. Idk if this is best practice or just my personal preference. But I tend to avoid ending scripts when possible so the code runs its natural course.

Comment: @dee yes. The file will be used by multiple users

Comment: IMO you should use some database software, like Access or MySQL or some other DB as already suggested by Comintern. Excel is not a DB and it might be very frustrating to synchronize the data for more users in one excel file. https://learn.g2crowd.com/free-database-software

Comment: @dee we will eventually migrate to SQL. We're just doing it this way for the time being. Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting aside any criticism of the solution's architecture, what your code is missing is the assignment to the `answer` variable:

```
answer = MsgBox("This batch has already been deposited!" & vbCrLf & "Rework?", vbYesNo, "Rework?")
```

Use `Option Explicit` and declare your variables with the appropriate types ([check out this article](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)).

A cleaned-up version of your code might look something like this:

```
Option Explicit 'At the very top of your module.

'... Other code ...

Private Sub gbatchd_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer) 'Check DB for duplicate value
    Dim wsDepo As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim rngFound As Excel.Range
    Dim sValueToFind As String
    Dim answer As VbMsgBoxResult

    If KeyCode = KeyCodeConstants.vbKeyReturn Then
        'Barcode reader has sent the Enter (Return) key.
        'Attempt to find the value.
        sValueToFind = Trim(gbatchd.Text)
        Set wsDepo = dbgrids.Worksheets("Deposition")
        Set rngFound = wsDepo.Columns(1).Find(What:=sValueToFind, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
            'Value was found. Ask whether it is a rework.
            answer = MsgBox("This batch has already been deposited!" & vbCrLf & "Rework?", vbYesNo, "Rework?")
            If answer = VbMsgBoxResult.vbYes Then
                wsDepo.Cells(rngFound.Row, 5).Value = "Rework"
            End If
        End If

        'Cleanup.
        Set rngFound = Nothing
        Set wsDepo = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent... ;-)

Comment: @Excelosaurus I'm sorry for giving you that much work. I declared the variables outside the sub, since they'll be used in other subs as well. But thank you for your answer and your time. I'm going to test this out as soon as I get to work tomorrow.

Comment: @Excelosaurus I've tried your suggestion, but "Rework" is added in a new row at the very end of the range

Comment: @Excelosaurus nevermind. Your code worked. I messed up the order of the variables. Thank you for your help.